# How is the "Supervisor" constructed in the TimeGAN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am exploring the TimeGAN architecture (Yoon, et al) and I have studied the code from the original authors, https://github.com/jsyoon0823/TimeGAN/blob/master/timegan.py, and a revised code written in TensorFlow 2, https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-synthetic/blob/e4cace4fb5c7ac47604364fbf300c7b072faab8a/src/ydata_synthetic/synthesizers/timeseries/timegan/model.py#L339. The actual paper seems to lack many details of the TimeGAN architecture, specifically details relating to the supervisor model. Line 132 of the first reference show that the intended input for the supervisor is the 'H', the latent representation. In Line 170 and 171, the supervisor is given two separate inputs, 'E-Hat' which produces'H_hat', and 'H' which produces 'H_hat_supervise'. The supervised loss is defined as the MSE of these two ('H' and 'H_hat_supervised'). This part doesn't make sense. If 'H' is the input to the supervisor and it's output is being directly compared to 'H'. Wouldn't this just enforce the supervior to be identity? Also, the trainable variables for this loss are defined as the the generator weights and the supervisor weights. Why are the generator weights included in this when the generator is not used in producing 'H' or 'H_hat_supervised'?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the supervisor goal, as commented in the code, is "Generate next sequence using the previous sequence" (line 133 in the source file). Accordignly, the supervised loss is between `H_hat_supervised` and a **shifted** version of `H` (line 200 in the source file):

```
G_loss_S = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(H[:,1:,:], H_hat_supervise[:,:-1,:])
```

which is (I guess, I didn't read the paper yet) what you want. In addition, the supervisor's output is also used in the discriminator, and in the creation of `X_hat`, so anyway it wouldn't converge into the identity.

Regarding your 2nd question, I am also wondering about it, as it looks redundant -- the supervised loss does not depend on these weights and it seems they will not get updated during backprop of this loss.